# Are poly1305 authenticators distinguishable from random data?

Tags: randomness, poly1305

Assume Alice authenticates a message $M$ with nonce $N$ and secret key $K$, creating authenticator $A$. She then sends $A$ across the network.

[The **Poly1305** paper](http://cr.yp.to/mac/poly1305-20050329.pdf) does not seem to specify whether it is possible for an adversary, whom has seen $A$, to determine whether $A$ is just random bytes or has characteristics of an output from poly1305.

For someone interested in deniability, this is an important distinction. Are poly1305 authenticators distinguishable from random data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they are not distinguishable from random.

The Poly1305-AES authenticator is defined as:

$$
(((c_1 r^q + c_2 r^{q−1} + ... + c_q r^1 ) \bmod {(2^{130} - 5)}) + \operatorname{AES}_k (N)) \bmod 2^{128}
$$

Since it is the sum of an AES output and some other number modulo $2^{128}$, it is PRF if:

- the AES output is PRF and
- the two numbers are independent.

AES output looks like PRF as long as you see less than ~$2^{64}$ of them and $k$ and $r$ are required to be independent (since they are chosen from a uniform distribution), so the authenticators are indistinguishable from random at least as long as you see significantly fewer than $2^{64}$ of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the authenticator might be distinguishable from random data if the key has some structure. For example, if the first half of the key is 0 or if the authenticated message has zero length, the authenticator tag will be exactly the second half of the key.

See the following python code for proof:

```
import tlslite
import random

# poly1305 will leak the second half of the key if
second_half = [1, 3, 3, 7, 1, 3, 3, 7, 1, 3, 3, 7, 1, 3, 3, 7]

# the first half of the key is 0
first_half = [0]*16
poly_key = first_half + second_half
poly = tlslite.utils.poly1305.Poly1305(poly_key)
message = b"this text does not matter"
print(list(poly.create_tag(message)))

# or the authenticated message is empty
first_half = [random.randrange(256) for _ in range(16)]
poly_key = first_half + second_half
poly = tlslite.utils.poly1305.Poly1305(poly_key)
message = b""
print(list(poly.create_tag(message)))

# in both cases, tag will be the second half of the key
```

Comment: The key is uniform random, so this observation has no consequences.  There's a $2^{-128}$ chance of having the first half of the key be zero.

Comment: ... and since the second half of the key is uniformly random, even if the first half were zero or the message empty, it would still be indistinguishable from random data.